# Port 80 blocked

Tags: apache, centos, port, iptables, rhel

So I've been trying for the past several hours to get my port 80 opened, so that I can access my Apache server. I'm running RHEL 6.5, and below is the configuration for my iptables.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Jul  2 12:59:50 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9:1332]
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
## Open 443 port i.e. HTTPS
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul  2 12:59:50 2014
```

I've saved them and restarted, to no avail. I am using a port checker (http://www.checkmyports.net/) to check if it is open, but it isn't. Before you mark this as a duplicate, I have tried everything online. I've reconfigured my iptables multiple times, removed additional firewalls, disabled and re-enabled, and multiple other solutions, all to no avail. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Output of ps aux | grep 'httpd'
:

```
root     20353  0.0  0.7 175704  3668 ?        Ss   12:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   20355  0.0  0.4 175704  2408 ?        S    12:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   20356  0.0  0.4 175704  2408 ?        S    12:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   20357  0.0  0.4 175704  2408 ?        S    12:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   20358  0.0  0.4 175704  2408 ?        S    12:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   20359  0.0  0.4 175704  2408 ?        S    12:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   20360  0.0  0.4 175704  2408 ?        S    12:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   20361  0.0  0.4 175704  2408 ?        S    12:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   20362  0.0  0.4 175704  2408 ?        S    12:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     21624  0.0  0.1 103244   856 pts/0    S+   13:55   0:00 grep httpd
```

Output of netstat -tulpn:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State           PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN          960/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN        28361/sshd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36088               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      978/rpc.statd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1108/sendmail       
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      960/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      20353/httpd         
tcp        0      0 :::51733                    :::*                        LISTEN      978/rpc.statd       
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      28361/sshd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                               960/rpcbind         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39182               0.0.0.0:*                               978/rpc.statd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               20708/dhclient      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:711                 0.0.0.0:*                               960/rpcbind         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:730                 0.0.0.0:*                               978/rpc.statd       
udp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                                    960/rpcbind         
udp        0      0 :::711                      :::*                                    960/rpcbind         
udp        0      0 :::35278                    :::*                                    978/rpc.statd
```

Comment: If disabling iptables still keeps port 80 blocked, you are either having an issue with the routers firewall or you are behind a nat. If you are behind a nat you need to forward port 80 to your webserver through it.

Comment: Port 80 traffic could be blocked by your ISP. Its common practice

Answer (score 0):

Ensure there is something running on that port.

If you have port 80 open on your firewall but nothing is listening on that port (apache,http) then the port will show as closed.

Whats the output of

```
ps aux | grep 'httpd'
```

and

```
netstat -tulpn
```

Comment: Added those responses.

Answer (score 0):

You could try clearing out iptables entirely, get the web access working, and then turn it back on.

I have an iptables-clear.sh script that I run to do this.

Note this doesn't use the /etc/init.d version of iptables which you might have to turn off while you're fixing this. Just remember to turn it back on once you're done.

```
# Flush all tables
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

# Default policy to ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```